# How sensitive are early universe abundance calculations to the neutron half-life?

Tags: cosmology, nucleosynthesis, elemental-abundances, neutrons

Phys.org's [Physicists announce the world's most precise measurement of neutron lifetime](https://phys.org/news/2021-10-physicists-world-precise-neutron-lifetime.html) discusses the accepted for publication Phys. Rev. Letter *Improved neutron lifetime measurement with UCNτ* (links in block quote) and says:

> An international team of physicists led by researchers at Indiana University Bloomington has announced the world's most precise measurement of the neutron's lifetime.
>
> The results from the team, which encompasses scientists from over 10 national labs and universities in the United States and abroad, represent **a more than two-fold improvement** over [previous measurements](https://phys.org/news/2018-05-levitation-yields-neutron-lifetime.html)—with an uncertainty of **less than one-tenth of a percent.**
>
> The work is [reported](https://journals.aps.org/prl/accepted/b4074Yc6S6b1c98cc3e829630f8de021af1aba78c) in the Oct 13 issue of the journal Physical Review Letters. It was also the subject of a live news briefing at the 2021 Fall Meeting of the American Physical Society Division of Nuclear Physics. [A pre-print version of the paper is also available (arXiv)](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2106.10375.pdf).

The article begins:

> Introduction.
>
> The decay $n \rightarrow p + e^- + \bar{\nu}_e$ is the simplest example of nuclear β-decay. The mean neutron
> lifetime τn provides a key input for predicting primordial light element abundances <sup>1</sup>.
>
> <sup>1</sup>[Big Bang Nucleosynthesis with a New Neutron Lifetime](https://journals.aps.org/prd/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevD.71.021302) ([arXiv](https://arxiv.org/abs/astro-ph/0408523))

The half-live was already known to better than one part in a thousand, the improvement is now substantially better than a part in a thousand.

**Question:** How sensitive are early universe abundance calculations to the neutron half-life?

For example, are there some abundances that are much more sensitive than others to the neutron half-life? If for example some processes involve neutrons after 10 half-lives, then the remaining neutrons vary by 10 parts per thousand for a one part per thousand in half-life.

I understand that the neutron half-life measurement is important for several other reasons in particle physics, I'm just asking about the implications for abundances.

Comment: 3 questions in 3 hours

Comment: @WalidSiddik I'm an SE addict, I confess! If you search the main meta (or even just Math SE meta) you'll see I'm not the only one!

Comment: I am surprised the paper does not appear to address this point, since it is listed as one of the motivations for the work. There is a bit of a lever arm, so that the effects on primordial abundance predictions are bigger than 1 part in a thousand.